# How to send data to specific client in a specific room with socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

My question is what's the proper way of sending data to a specific client in a specific room. I'm using socket io and the code written below:

I use the command:

```
socket.to(socket.id).emit('change', {data})
```

but the client never gets this command. Anyone know why?

Below is a snippet of my code:

server code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('channelJoin', function(channel){
        socket.join(channel);

        if(deltasByChannel[channel])
        {
            console.log("sending initial data to: "+socket.id);
            socket.to(socket.id).emmit('change', deltasByChannel[channel]);
        }

        socket.on("change", function(delta){
            console.log("channel: " + channel+" was edited!");
            console.log(deltasByChannel[channel]);
            deltasByChannel[channel] ? deltasByChannel[channel] = deltasByChannel[channel].concat(delta) : deltasByChannel[channel] = delta;
            socket.broadcast.to(channel).emit('change', delta);
        });
    });
});


http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

client code:

```
var channel = window.location.pathname;
var socket = io.connect();

//Ace handlers
var sendUpdateData = function(e){
    socket.emit("change", [e.data]);
};



socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.on("change", function(data){
        console.log("change event received!");
        editor.getSession().removeListener('change', sendUpdateData);
        editor.getSession().getDocument().applyDeltas(data);
        editor.getSession().on('change', sendUpdateData);
    });
    editor.getSession().on('change', sendUpdateData);

    socket.emit('channelJoin', channel);
});
```

just to avoid confusion the editor object is listening for a change event as well. It's from an entirely different library (ace.js) that has nothing to do with my socket io issue.

below is another snippet of the server code for more clarity:

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you instantiate the `http` object, and connect the `io` object to the server, probably using the `listen` method?

Comment: ok, I put another snippet of that part in.

Comment: I assume `emmit` is a typo, and you're really using `emit`?

Comment: I think you should be using `io.to(socket.id).emit('change', {data})` but can you also verify that `socket.id` in this context is equal to `channel`?

Comment: They are not equal. Channel is just an arbitrary string, a sort of chatroom that several users can be in. I use socket.to(channel).broadcast to send messages to all users in a "chat room".

Socket.id is is the individual connection. It's some randomly generated string. I've seen people use socket.id in other places to send data to an individual, but what about a specific individual in a specific room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62058/discussion-between-bencripps-and-brian-yeh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's some confusion about sending data over sockets using `socket.io`. You can elect to emit events or data using `rooms` or private namesspaces, you can broadcast to all connected sockets, or you can emit data to a specific ID.

In your case you should just be selecting a `socket.id`, to emit an event to a particular connection. You can do this by:

`io.sockets.connected[ socket.id ].emit('privateMsg', 'hello this is a private msg');`

You can also use the `to()` method in conjunction with `broadcast` as well:

`socket.broadcast.to( socket.id ).emit('privateMsg', 'hello this is a private msg');`

This will reach the user which matches the `socket.id` you pass in as the argument.

To contact users within a "room" or private namespace, you can also use the `to()` method:

`io.to('some room').emit('some event');`

In this case `some room` would be the `channel` var you've defined, and it should match a predefined variable that has already been instantiated.

For more information about rooms/namespaces/and reaching specific socket connections:  http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#

Comment: I'm not the OP, but boy, I'd disagree that socket.io has good documentation.  It's pretty, but extremely lacking in content.  Just try to find the document for `io.to()`.  It doesn't exist.  It's an empty section in the doc.  It seems likely from other examples that you can use it to broadcast to a chatroom, but you have to infer that from other examples and it is not clear at all whether it can be used for other purposes like sending to a particular socket.  Please show us where in the doc one can figure out that you can do this: `io.sockets.connected[ socket.id ].emit(...)`.

Comment: I guess I've found that method to work in my own work, but `socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);` is shown here in the docs: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/# didn't mean to start a war, i just think the guys at socket have done a nice job

Comment: I like the socket.io functionality a lot.  The doc is pretty bad.  I could only figure out simple things I needed to do by setting breakpoints and inspecting socket.io data structures and methods in the debugger.  It shouldn't be that hard.  Seriously, you use `socket.broadcast.to()` to send to a single socket and the code example for that is in the chat rooms part of the doc?  That's odd.